# Get input email address from ACS when using LiveID

Tags: windows-live-id, acs, liveid

Is it in any way possible to wire up an ACS rule to return/PassThrough the user's email adress from ACS using $(InputValue) when using Live ID?

I am using Passive authentication and get redirected out to Live ID but I was wondering if there is any way to wire up a rule from ACS that might get the InputValue email address

From what I can see I think this might be possible by hosting a login page of course but I would prefer to be able to get it in some other way from ACS if possible.

(I should have added that the current scenario is to implement Live ID authentication on top of an existing ASP.Net application with a database backend for user identity and roles.)

Extra information related to the current scenario : The current scenario is an EXISTING system with its own home-grown database authentication security model.  I tried all sorts of ways to see if I could intercept the user's email address and eventually decided the available approaches for doing this were not desirable (in this specific scenario).

The only suitable and secure pattern found to transition to Live ID authentication in this scenarioo is to build a Registration system around your application which allows an existing user to register their LiveID and then bring them back to your application to capture their Live ID 'nameidentifier'.

However, given that any unknown user could do this it would be necessary to have an interim authentication step via email or some-such mechanism to validate the Live ID email address being used.

I hope this is of help to someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to get any identifiable claims when using ACS with Windows Live. This is due to Windows Live user privacy policy.

With windows live you will only get a ID claim which is unique to your Relying Party application.

Comment: Seems to be a bizarre limitation of the built-in STS for Windows Live. It's not much work at all to build a custom STS for Live that uses the server-side connect API to append additional claims, including user's full name + email: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243649.aspx.

Comment: This is not true. The information can be achieved (see answer by @Nariman) but is not accessible directly from the token

Answer (score 1):

Possible but it requires a bit of code for a custom sts:

https://gist.github.com/1867792

Code doesn't build and dependencies aren't included... but it's largely based off an early thinktecture starter site ported to MVC4 with changes shown above.